# php mysqli_query error numbers

Tags: php, mysql

I'm executing MySQL database querys in my PHP scrpt like this:

```
function doStuffInDB(){
    ...
    if (($r = mysqli_query($db_conn, $q)) === false) {
        throw new Exception(mysqli_error($db_conn));
    } else {
       //get result
    }
    ...
}
```

When I call the function which executes the query, I call it like this:

```
function doStuff(){
    try{
        doStuffInDB();
    }catch(Exception $e){
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

I would like to write a generic error handler that takes the error number of the error that occurred and returns an error message to the user. Something like:

```
function doStuff(){
    try{
        doStuffInDB();
    }catch(Exception $e){
        echo $feedback = handleError($e->getErrorNumber());
    }
}
```

For me to do this, I need a list of error numbers which can occur while calling `mysqli_query()` but I can not find any such list. Where can I find this documentation? Any tip on how this error handler (a php function) would look like?

Comment: Something like this? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/error-messages-server.html

Comment: The clear text message in the exception is most probably more helpful and less work.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider Its clear for someone with an understanding of databases, but I want to write errors for users who have no experience with databases

Comment: Well, will this be helpful to the user? If the user can't do anything about it, a generic "There is a problem with the database"  error message along with a mail to an admin or a log entry with details from the exception might be more useful.

Comment: Yes it will be helpful. Imagine the case that the table has been deleted. The error number will be X and we can formulate an error message saying e.g. "Database error: contact admin". But if the user tries to insert a PK value that already exists, the error no will be Y and we can show an error message saying "The entry already exists, check your values". I would say that this is better error handling than just returning "Datebase error" everytime. Do you follow? @GeraldSchneider

Comment: @CD001 Are those error codes the same codes I would get if I did `$e->getCode();`?

Comment: Those are the MySQL error numbers you'd get from `mysqli_errno()` : `$e->getCode()` will return the PHP severity code based on the constant (e.g. `E_USER_ERROR` = 256) - there's no correlation between the MYSQL error code and the Exception code though you could sub-class the `Exception` object to cover it.